# Proof of Reduction Formula for $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x^2} dx$

Tags: integration

I have attempted both **substitution** and **integration by parts** upon the following problem (and both in conjunction) to no avail. The reduction formula given remains quite elusive.

Let $$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^ne^{-x^2}dx.$$
Hence, show that $$I_n = \frac{n-1}{2}I_{n-2}, \ n \geq 2.$$

I have the following:

$$I_n = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^ne^{-x^2} dx \\ = \left[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}x^{n-1}\right]_0^\infty - \int_{0}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}(n-1)x^{n-2}dx \\ =  \left[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}x^{n-1}\right]_0^\infty + \frac{1}{2(n-1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}x^{n-2}dx \\ = \left[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}x^{n-1}\right]_0^\infty + \frac{1}{2(n-1)}I_{n-2} \\ = \frac{1}{2(n-1)}I_{n-2} \ \ \mathrm{due \ to \ fact \ that:} \ \  \lim_{x \to \infty}x^{n-1}e^{-x^2}=0$$

Which is not quite the solution. Where have I erred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

When integrating by parts, let $u=x^{n-1}$ and $v=-\frac12 e^{-x^2}$.

Also, use the fact that for all $n$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^{n-1}e^{-x^2}=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much! There appears to be an error somewhere in my method (included in original post). Could you indicate it for me?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure. It appears you "flipped" the $(n-1)/2$ after the third "equal to" sign.  Otherwise, well done!

Comment: One last question. How is it that you arrived at $u = x^{n-1}$ and $v = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: The derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ is $-2xe^{x^2}$.  So, in order for $u\,dv$ to equal the initial integrand, what does $u$ need to be?

Comment: Ah I see. It would be $-\frac{1}{2}x^{n-1}$. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if $v=-\frac12\,e{-x^2}$, then $u=x^{n-1}$.  But I'm pleased to see that you've got it now.